# Divide items of a column by one-item column

Tags: text-processing, awk, arithmetic

How to iteratively divide the elements of a column by a one-element item in another column?

Eg, Input:

```
2     2
2.2
4
44
```

Expected Output:

```
1
1.1
2
22
```

Standard division `awk '{print $1/$2}' Input > Output` is not working (as iterating through all non-exixting `$2` elements)

Comment: How about `'FNR==1 {d=$2} {print $1/d}'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the divisor you need to consider the value at the first row of the second column only. You can use `FNR` for this. In awk, `FNR` refers to the record number (practically the line number) in the current file. Store the divisor by reading the first row of second column and divide the elements in first column by the stored value.

> `awk 'FNR==1 {d=$2} {print $1/d}' Input > Output`